# How to use 2 updates function in UserController in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.8

I am trying to add user profile picture and also btc wallet to an input. If I add the wallet I can not add the profile img. I saw that both use the update function and so I am having conflict, if I remove the route from the wallet, the photo is good, but I need the 2 ok.

My Route btc:

```
Route::get('userp', 'UserController@index');
Route::post('userp', 'UserController@update');
```

my route img profile:

```
Route::post('userp', 'UserController@update_avatar');
```

my controller update btc:

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $data = \Input::all();

    $valida = [
        'passaport' => 'passaport',
        'nascimento' => 'date',
        'bitzpayer_email' => 'email'
    ];

    if (!empty($data['password'])) {
        $valida = array_merge($valida, ['password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',]);
    }
    if (\Auth::user()->ativo == 0 && \Auth::user()->dataAtivacao == '0000-00-00') {
        $valida = array_merge($valida, ['pacote' => 'required|integer',]);
    }
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $valida);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/userp')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
    }
    if (!isset($data['saque'])) {
        if (!empty($data['bitzpayer_id'])) {
            if (!$this->checkAddress($data['bitzpayer_id'])) {
                return redirect('/userp')->withErrors(['Invalid Wallet.']);
            }
        }
        $dados = [
            'bitzpayer_id' => @$data['bitzpayer_id'],
        ];
    } else {
        $dados = [
            'bitzpayer_id' => @$data['bitzpayer_id'],
         ];
    }

    if (\Auth::user()->ativo == 0 && \Auth::user()->dataAtivacao == '0000-00-00') {
        $dados['pacote'] = $data['pacote'];
    }
    if (!empty($data['password'])) {
        $senha = \DB::table('users')->where('id', \Auth::user()->id)->first()->password;
        if (\Hash::check($data['current_password'], $senha)) {
            $dados = array_merge($dados, ['password' => bcrypt($data['password']),]);
        } else {
            return redirect('userp')->withErrors(['Senha inválida, tente novamente.']);
        }
    }

    $user = \Auth::user()->update($dados);
    if ($user) { 
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Your bitcoin wallet has been updated successfully!');
    } else {
        return redirect('/userp')->withErrors(['Não foi possivel atualizar suas informações, tente novamente.']);
    }
}
```

My profile picture controller:

```
public function update_avatar(Request $request) {
    if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename ));

        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->avatar = $filename;
        $user->save();
    }
    return view('userp', array('userp' => Auth::user()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If u want to update why not you use put method.
2. In the end of update function

   `if ($user) { 
       return $this->update_avatar($request);
   }else {
       return redirect('/userp')->withErrors(['Não foi possivel atualizar suas informações, tente novamente.']);
   }`

Pass avatar file in $request

Comment: also does not work, I believe it is something simple, for example the button submit

Comment: thanks for the help but still the error still, this return is from the btc wallet, it is ok but the profile picture is not

Comment: Then check the request contain image file. it should contain not only variable but also with whole file

Comment: yes it works but for this I need to remove btc routes from the web as they don't work together

Comment: Try after remove your Request like....     **public function update_avatar($request){**